# How to change the selection of input From UserName To PassWord in React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm New in react, I have a login page with 2 input ( UserName and Password ). I want when I insert userName and press enter selection change and goto password input

```
render() {

 <input className="input100 backUserImage" maxLength="20" type="text" 
        name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" placeholder="userName" />
 <input className="input100 backPassImage" maxLength="20" 
        type="password" name="txtPassWord" id="txtPassWord" placeholder="password" />

}
```

Comment: That's a bad practice. Normally `enter` in Forms means submission. `Tab` in Form means switching from one input to another.

Comment: I think that would be automatically working with the tab key. And binding it with enter key is not a good option as enter key is for submit button by default

Comment: @PrateekThapa you mean I should change the selection from form? how?

Comment: I mean let the form handle itself. You don't need to overdo a `Login` form. Make sure you show appropriate errors and once the form is submitted, it performs the login operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the inputs in a form and add a submit button. Submit button will work with enter key and tab key will work for input fields switching

```
<>
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> //you have to write handleSubmit function
<div className="form-group">
<input className="input100 backUserImage" maxLength="20" type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" placeholder="userName" /> 
<input className="input100 backPassImage" maxLength="20" type="password" name="txtPassWord" id="txtPassWord" placeholder="کلمه عبور" /> 
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

For detailed explaination and examples, check out the [forms in official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on the second input tag once you are done with the first input tag. You can achieve by doing this way.

```
    <input
        ref={(input) => {
          this.nameInput = input;
        }}
      />
      <input
        ref={(input) => {
          this.passinput = input;
        }}
      />
      <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
        <input
          className="btn btn-primary"
          value="Reserve Now"
          onClick={()=>{this.passinput.focus();}}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        />
      </div>
```

You can add your validations and do the focus above snippet is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner I highly recommend taking a look at the documentation on **How to handle form in react.**
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
This is the best way to learn any technology.

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.nameFocus = React.createRef();
    this.passFocus = React.createRef();
    this.captchaFocus = React.createRef();
    this.submitFocus = React.createRef();
}

handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' || event.key === 'Tab') {
        switch(event.target.name){
            case 'txtUserName':
                if ($("#txtUserName").val().length !== 0) {
                    ($("#txtPassWord").val().length === 0) ? this.passFocus.current.focus() : this.captchaFocus.current.focus();
                }
            case 'txtPassWord':
                if ($("#txtPassWord").val().length !== 0) {
                    ($("#txtUserName").val().length === 0) ? this.nameFocus.current.focus() : this.captchaFocus.current.focus();
                }
            case 'txtCaptcha': {
                if ($("#txtCaptcha").val().length !== 0) {
                    if ($("#txtPassWord").val().length !== 0 && $("#txtUserName").val().length !== 0) {
                        this.submitFocus.current.focus()
                    }else if ($("#txtUserName").val().length === 0) {
                        this.nameFocus.current.focus()
                    }else if ($("#txtPassWord").val().length === 0) {
                        this.passFocus.current.focus()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }

  <input className="input100 backUserImage" ref={this.nameFocus} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} maxLength="20" type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" placeholder="UserName"} />
```

the rest of inputs have a same type but defrent `ref={this.nameFocus}`